# Saving a dataframe in the parquet format generates too many small files

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

With Spark Sql I am saving a spark df in the parquet format in a hive table.
The problem is that this operation generate always around 200 part-* files of 3 MBs. How is it possible to control the number of the output files and the number of partition during the processing? As i know that each partition generates one part-* file.

How my workflow looks like:

1. I read a partition from a table in the Hive metastore with `spark.read.parquet("")`
2. Then I create a TempView from this df
3. Then I do the transformations i need with pure sql, which have a lot of joins: `spark.sql("SQL QUERY")`
4. Then I try to do a *repartition* or *coalesce* on the results, which does not work as the number of the part-* files will be always 200
5. I save my df with `spark.sql(" insert overwrite partition() ... ")`

The reason i am working with pure sql is because i loose the ordering of my columns if try to save my df with the Dataframe API.

I am using Spark 2.2.0 in CDH 11.2

If there are some non charities in my question please let me know.

**UPDATE1:** *sample source code*

```
conf = (SparkConf()
.set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","SNAPPY")
.set("spark.executor.cores", "3")
.set("spark.executor.instances", "10")
.set("spark.executor.memory", "20g")
)

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .getOrCreate()

df=spark.read.parquet("/user/hive/warehouse/schema.db/tbl/year=2000/month=01/day=01").cache()

temp_table_name="tmp_bal2_nor_20000101"
df.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name)

aaa=spark.sql(
""" select DISTINCT t.A,
                    t.lot,
                    t.of,
                    t.columns,
                    .
                    .,
    from temp_table_name t 
left join( 
    ...
) tmp1 on ...
left join( 
    ...
) tmp2 on ...
left join( 
    ...
) tmp3 ...
left join( 
    ...
) tmp4 on ...
left join( 
    ...
) tmp5 on ...
left join( 
    ...
) tmp6 on ...
order by t.A, t.lot """
)

aaa.coalesce(10).createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name)
spark.sql(""" insert overwrite table tbl1
PARTITION(year=2000, month=01, day=01)
select DISTINCT t.A, 
                 t.lot, 
                 t.of, 
                 t.columns
from temp_table_name t
""")

spark.stop()
```

Comment: hello @sdikby coalesce should work. You need show writer's code in order to make conclusions though. Can you post some code?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis Please check my update.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your code in order to save parquet file after using coalesce. As next:

```
 aaa.coalesce(10).write.parquet("your_path")
```

otherwise coalesce will normally be ignored since after reducing your partitions you are creating TempView with *aaa* dataset. Currently you have 200 partitions because *spark.sql.shuffle.partitions* is set to 200, this is the default partitions number for Spark SQL. coalesce is just part of your dataset therefore if you want to use it properly you need to do it directly through your dataset.

Comment: if i follow your advice, then my data will be not accessible through the hive metastore (i tried to view them through HUE but i get an error). The second issue is that with `.write.parquet("path")`, the order of the columns is not the same as my target table

Comment: well you can save your data and then restore it into your TempView as an alternative

Comment: You mean after i do my transformations, I coalesce my df save it in a temp dir, then re-read it and finally do i spark.sql("insert overwrite into ...") ? 
I will test it, but is there a more "direct" approach?

Comment: as far as I know a direct approach to create a TempView after calling coalesce, as you need it here, there is not

Comment: I have tested your approach and, i would say, it has made things worse. The number of part files jumped from 200 to 37.266
I did exactly as i described in my previous comment

Comment: @sdikby sorry I didn't realize that you need to keep your spark sql part as it is I thought we were talking over if you should replace it with dataframes or not, my bad. So do not save any dataframe instead I would suggest to change `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` in order to modify your default partion number for spark sql. You could try to set it to a lower number